# Can flex have a transparent bg over the browser like Flash and can it work with a jquery overlay?

Tags: jquery, apache-flex, flash

so right now im using shadowbox jquery overlay, but was wondering if I could have a transparent background and use the overlay in tandem.

Is there a way to export it like in flash?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a similar effect in flex? If you can put a swf in the shadowbox? If there are monsters under your bed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You do not need to touch the flash file.

Choose "Transparent" in the *WMODE* setting within your html template to make the Flash movie's background disappear in browsers which support this feature.

Or

in your html file

Add the following parameter to the *OBJECT* tag:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

Add the following parameter to the *EMBED* tag

```
wmode="transparent"
```

**Edited** , you need to change the background alpha in your `<mx:Application>` tag add `backgroundAlpha="0"` or to a value you feel comfortable with.

Comment: what should I do to the flex app? mine still shows the default gradient background.

Comment: You need to change the `backgroundAlpha` in your Applicaton tag. Check the edited info above.